# Error 5 partition table invalid or corrupt

Tags: raid, partition, boot, grub

I'm trying to add a second SSD to a Centos 6 system. But I get the `Error 5 partition table invalid or corrupt` at boot.

The system already has a single SSD (sdb) and a pair of HDDs (sd{a,c}) in a RAID 1 array from where it boots. It is as if the new SSD assumes one of the devices of the RAID array. Is it? How to avoid that or rearrange the setup?

```
# cat fstab

UUID=967b4035-782d-4c66-b22f-50244fe970ca /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=86fd06e9-cdc9-4166-ba9f-c237cfc43e02 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=72552a7a-d8ae-4f0a-8917-b75a6239ce9f /ssd                    ext4    discard,relatime    1 2
UUID=8000e5e6-caa2-4765-94f8-9caeb2bda26e swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0

# ll /dev/disk/by-id/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 15 23:50 ata-OCZ-VERTEX3_OCZ-43DSRFTNCLE9ZJXX -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 ata-OCZ-VERTEX3_OCZ-43DSRFTNCLE9ZJXX-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 15 23:50 ata-ST3500413AS_5VMT49E3 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 ata-ST3500413AS_5VMT49E3-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 ata-ST3500413AS_5VMT49E3-part2 -> ../../sdc2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 ata-ST3500413AS_5VMT49E3-part3 -> ../../sdc3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 15 23:50 ata-ST3500413AS_5VMTJNAJ -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 ata-ST3500413AS_5VMTJNAJ-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 ata-ST3500413AS_5VMTJNAJ-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 ata-ST3500413AS_5VMTJNAJ-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 15 23:50 md-name-localhost.localdomain:0 -> ../../md0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 15 23:50 md-name-localhost.localdomain:1 -> ../../md1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 15 23:50 md-name-localhost.localdomain:2 -> ../../md2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 15 23:50 md-uuid-a04d7241:8da6023e:f9004352:107a923a -> ../../md1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 15 23:50 md-uuid-a22c43b9:f1954990:d3ddda5e:f9aff3c9 -> ../../md0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 15 23:50 md-uuid-f403a2d0:447803b5:66edba73:569f8305 -> ../../md2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 15 23:50 scsi-SATA_OCZ-VERTEX3_OCZ-43DSRFTNCLE9ZJXX -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 scsi-SATA_OCZ-VERTEX3_OCZ-43DSRFTNCLE9ZJXX-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 15 23:50 scsi-SATA_ST3500413AS_5VMT49E3 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 scsi-SATA_ST3500413AS_5VMT49E3-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 scsi-SATA_ST3500413AS_5VMT49E3-part2 -> ../../sdc2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 scsi-SATA_ST3500413AS_5VMT49E3-part3 -> ../../sdc3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 15 23:50 scsi-SATA_ST3500413AS_5VMTJNAJ -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 scsi-SATA_ST3500413AS_5VMTJNAJ-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 scsi-SATA_ST3500413AS_5VMTJNAJ-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 scsi-SATA_ST3500413AS_5VMTJNAJ-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 15 23:50 wwn-0x5000c500383621ff -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 wwn-0x5000c500383621ff-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 wwn-0x5000c500383621ff-part2 -> ../../sdc2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 wwn-0x5000c500383621ff-part3 -> ../../sdc3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 15 23:50 wwn-0x5000c5003838b2e7 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 wwn-0x5000c5003838b2e7-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 wwn-0x5000c5003838b2e7-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 wwn-0x5000c5003838b2e7-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 15 23:50 wwn-0x5e83a97f592139d6 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 15 23:50 wwn-0x5e83a97f592139d6-part1 -> ../../sdb1

# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x79298ec9

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1       14594   117219328   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d99de

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1        1275    10240000   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc2   *        1275        1339      512000   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc3            1339       60802   477633536   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b3327

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1        1275    10240000   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2   *        1275        1339      512000   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3            1339       60802   477633536   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md0: 10.5 GB, 10484641792 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 2559727 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md2: 489.1 GB, 489095557120 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 119408095 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md2 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md1: 524 MB, 524275712 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 127997 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

# cat /etc/grub.conf 
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd2,1)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64)
    root (hd2,1)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=UUID=967b4035-782d-4c66-b22f-50244fe970ca rd_MD_UUID=f403a2d0:447803b5:66edba73:569f8305 rd_MD_UUID=a22c43b9:f1954990:d3ddda5e:f9aff3c9 rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=br-abnt2 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64.img
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not fix it directly so I took the new SSD and installed it in my desktop and there it was partitioned and formated.

Then in the server I edited the `fstab` commenting the old SSD line and adding a new one with a generic device spec:

```
#UUID=72552a7a-d8ae-4f0a-8917-b75a6239ce9f /ssd                    ext4    discard,relatime    1 2
/dev/sdb1 /ssd                    ext4    discard,relatime    1 2
```

Then I poweredoff the server and swapped the old SSD for the new one.

Once rebooted I edited the device specification for the respective UUID:

```
$ ll /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 16 14:02 14a9f494-4cba-4afe-b90e-82f3f131097f -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 16 14:02 8000e5e6-caa2-4765-94f8-9caeb2bda26e -> ../../md0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 16 14:02 86fd06e9-cdc9-4166-ba9f-c237cfc43e02 -> ../../md1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jun 16 14:02 967b4035-782d-4c66-b22f-50244fe970ca -> ../../md2
```

The new `fstab`:

```
#UUID=72552a7a-d8ae-4f0a-8917-b75a6239ce9f /ssd                    ext4    discard,relatime       1 2                  
UUID=14a9f494-4cba-4afe-b90e-82f3f131097f /ssd                    ext4    discard,relatime        1 2
```

A new reboot and it was done.